# How do I delete specific nodes and children referenced in an external XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a large XML file and I need to delete the whole student node (and all child nodes within that student) in it where the OWNINST of one of the instance nodes matches one in another XML file.

My large XML file 'file1.xml' is in the following format:

```
<institution>
<ukprn>1234</ukprn>
<course>
    <courseID>1</courseID>
    <courseaim>X99</courseaim>
</course>
<student>
    <birthdate>30/10/1985</birthdate>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST>
        <FC>1</FC>
        <elq>4</elq>
    </instance>
</student>
<student>
    <birthdate>01/02/1999</birthdate>
    <ybj>76</jbj>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
        <FC>2</FC>
        <elq>2</elq>
    </instance>
    <instance>
        <OWNINST>654321|2</OWNINST>
        <FC>6</FC>
        <elq>1</elq>
    </instance>
</student>
```

There are multiple students each of which can have multiple instances and not all nodes are present for all students.

I have another xml file 'File2.xml' which is structured like this:

```
<studentstodelete>
    <OWNINST>555466|2</OWNINST>
    <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
</studentstodelete>
```

For each of the students in File2.xml, I would like to delete their entire student node (including child nodes) in File1.xml if their OWNINST is listed in File2.xml. Any students not listed in File2.xml should not be changed.

Please could someone help with this as I don't know how to tell it to delete the records.

This is what I had come up with for my stylesheet but the 'delete' bit is missing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstodelete/OWNINST]">
</xsl:template>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the `Student` element then you need to change

```
<xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstodelete/OWNINST]">
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="Student[Instance/OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstodelete/OWNINST]"></xsl:template>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, knew I was nearly there!  Thanks very much.  You helped me yesterday too, thanks.  I tried to upvote you but it won't let me.